# ASP.NET Web API 2 breaks on page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I am having a strange issue with my ASP.NET Web API 2 application. When I open a new browser instance and load my application, everything works great -- requests return and everything functions as expected.  However, after a page refresh, everything stops working.  All subsequent requests timeout and fail to return responses.  Closing and re-opening the browser is the only thing that seems to resolve the issue.

To ensure that the API was receiving the requests, I added some logging to the Application_BeginRequest method in the Global.asax file.  The log lines are being written, so it appears that the requests are making it to that point, however, they do not enter the controller methods.  Once they timeout, they eventually find their way into the Application_EndRequest method.

The HTTPERR logs contain the following for failed requests:

> 2017-08-28 15:56:47 ::1%0 2815 ::1%0 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /api/ - - 1
>   Connection_Dropped API

My application is written in .NET Framework 4.6.1 and I'm using Visual Studio 2017 as my IDE.  The application is hosted locally in IIS 10.0 on Windows 10.  I am using Windows Integrated Security for authentication (NTLM) and the ASP.NET session behavior is set to 'Required'.  The issue occurs in both Debug and Release mode and does not appear to be tied to a specific browser.

Any idea what could be causing this?  I am relatively new to IIS so unfortunately I'm a bit lost here.

**Update**:
Setting 'runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests' to false in the Web.config seems to fix the issue.  I will need to dig a little deeper to figure out why that works...

Comment: In the browser, do you see any console errors?

Comment: Are the UI site and the Web API on two separate domains?

Comment: The browser console does not contain any errors.  Strangely, it doesn't even show the requests in the network tab (although I do see them in Fiddler).  The UI is hosted on a different site, but is on the same domain (localhost).  However, this behavior also occurs when accessing the API directly.

Comment: Setting 'runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests' to false in the Web.config seems to fix the issue.  I will need to dig a little deeper to figure out why that works...